# backup harddrive, so it can be restored perfectly

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, backup

i have windows installed on a SSD, and I am currently using Ubuntu from a usb install.

i want to make a complete backup of that SSD (120gb) to my internal HDD (1tb) so i can install ubuntu as my only operating system on the SSD.

i need to be able to access the files within the backup (pictures, work, ETC) untill everything is moved, but also if something goes wrong with ubuntu, need to be able to restore the complete harddrive, and it work perfectly as before, like nothing has ever happened

the reason is i have using a few linux distro's in the past, and i like them, but i end up reverting back to windows 7 from my dual boot because i am used to windows, and removing it from the harddrive will help me get used to linux, BUT put everything back to normal if i needed to

any ideas?, i need a complete harddrive backup, so the all i have to is tell it to copy back to the SSD without any issues

Comment: you can get more info here, [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are most familiar with Windows, and need ready access to your data files, I would suggest using Macrium Reflect Free Edition (http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx).  This will allow you to make a full backup of your hard drive, create a rescue disk so that you can restore it without having Windows loaded, and provide the facility to mount the disk image as a virtual disk under Windows in order to access the individual files and folders using Windows Explorer.